# How to display an iframe popup on button click in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

Hello I am new to Wordpress,
I've got a button which is Quick Enquiry which is placed at the bottom of my post.
I want to open an iframe on that button's click.

I tried a plugin named iframe popup,

```
<button style="background-color: #232254; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; width: 200px; height: 50px; border-radius: 15px 15px 15px;" onclick="forIframe();">Quick Enquiry</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function forIframe()
{[iframe-popup category="Category1"];}</script>
</div>
```

But nothing is working.

http://www.ithink.co/support_ticketing_system.html

Please visit this link, you will see a quick enquiry button. I want it exactly the same.
Thank you.

Comment: its working fine here

Comment: The given link is an example which I want to recreate in my wordpress post. - @RajKumarBhardwaj

Comment: are you use bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think that's an iframe, but a modal. Try using a modal plugin for wordpress such as this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/
EDIT: It is an iframe, but you can achieve this with a modal

Comment: iframe popup plugin only allows you to load an iframe in a modal box after x seconds. You cannot set it to activate upon a click event unfortunately.

Comment: @josephting so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @user2407398 I'll try thank you!

Comment: @ShitalMarakana its wordpress!

Answer (score 4):

you can create popup by using bootstrap in wordpress

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Quick Enquiry</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Quick Enquiry</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>[iframe-popup category="Category1"]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much!

Comment: Welcome :)
Happy to Help